# How can I set CornerRadius to 50%

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set CornerRadius to 50%

```xml
<Border Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="50%" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
      <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
</Border>
```

Comment: "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: I change the title, like url describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CornerRadius does not take percentages.

If you want to make a circle
just set it to the size of the width/2 or Height/2

in your case: 10